# How can i load one javascript after 20 or 30 second on my website

Tags: javascript

I want to load below javascript ad after 30 seconds on my wp site.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var uid = '219412';
   var wid = '586053';
   var pop_tag = document.createElement('script');pop_tag.src='//cdn.popcash.net/show.js';document.body.appendChild(pop_tag);
   pop_tag.onerror = function() {pop_tag = document.createElement('script');pop_tag.src='//cdn2.popcash.net/show.js';document.body.appendChild(pop_tag)};
</script>
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: wrap in a [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).. tip: google things you want to do before asking

Answer (score 1):

As @Lawrence Cherone already comments, you can wrap that javascript with `setTimeout()` function and provide a time of `20000-30000`.

example:

```
    <script>
       setTimeout(() => { /* your code */ }, 30000)
    </script>
```